# How to sequence CSS transform commands, one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

So I'm trying to move and rotate an object using CSS translate commands. I've found how to do the two translations simultaneously, but I want the object to rotate immediately, and then move toward another coordinate. If anyone has any suggestions they are well recieved :)

```
$rotate(d);
move(s * 2, point2[0], point2[1]);

function move(s, x, y) {
    $(".boat").css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate('+x+'px, '+y+'px)',
      'transform': 'translate('+x+'px, '+y+'px)',
      'transition': 'transform '+s+'ms',
      '-webkit-transition-timing-function': 'linear',
      'transition-timing-function': 'linear',
      '-webkit-transition-delay': '2s', /* Safari */
      'transition-delay': '2s'
     });
    }

function rotate(d)
{
  $(".boat").css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+d+'deg)',
    'transform': 'rotate('+d+'deg)'
  });
}
```

Comment: Tried adding `css` at `rotate` to `move` ?

Comment: Yes, because of the CSS rules, it takes the last transform statement, and performs that. So in your case it would ignore the rotate command :(

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do this with a callback function, that is, first invoke `rotate` function, and after it's done do the callback, e.g. `move`.

First, modify rotate function so that it accepts a callback and callback's arguments.

```
function rotate(d, cb, arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
  $(".boat").css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+d+'deg)',
    'transform': 'rotate('+d+'deg)'
  });

  if(typeof cb === 'function') cb(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

Then, when you start invoking functions, you'd invoke like this.

```
rotate(d, move, (s * 2), point2[0], point2[1]);
```

Ofcourse, instead of lining up `rotate` arguments like this, you can simply add them to an array and with `for each` loop forward arguments to the callback. I wrote just a simple example.

Edit:

If the callback still gets fired simultaneously, then try adding setTimeout of 1 or 100 milliseconds to it, e.g.

```
if(typeof cb === 'function'){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
       cb(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }, 1);
}
```